# Apache2, Not found my index.php file

Tags: apache2, php

Good Morning Guys,

I have a cluster project, I'm using `heartbeat`, `drbd`, `apache`, `php`, and `mysql`. So far my cluster drbd are working perfect! but When I tried to configure my `index.php` under this location `/etc/mnt/www`

I did the following.

Under `/etc/mnt/www`  I created a `index.php`
then I removed the default folder with `rm -rvf /var/www/`
I created the association with the new folder `ln -s /mnt/www/ /var/`

Then I went to the browser and when I type `192.168.1.100` I received `Not found, error 404`.

Is there any other configuration that I'm missing? Should I assign my `index.php` as default? if so where?

Please provide as much details as you can with a really good description and their location. I just started with Linux, so I'm a newbie on this situations.

Thanks in regards.

Guys Now I have the following error after I changed the `DocumentRoot` to `/mnt/www/index.php`

[image]

Also, I haven't done the DirectoryIndex part, since I dont know how to :

Comment: Please not that modern apache2 has its docroot in */var/www/html*, not simple */var/www*.

Comment: What is a docroot? I was following some instructions I found on the web and they said to delete .html and create .php. Did I screw it out?

Comment: This is a question answer site. Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1022637/edit) your question above when you have new information about the question. Do not put additional information about the question in "Your Answer". That space is for solutions. If you find a solution to the problem, then you should write your answer in the "Your Answer" windows.

Answer (score 1):

Check the Apache configuration and make sure that the `DocumentRoot` directory is properly set. You should also add a `DirectoryIndex` directive, so Apache will recognize `index.php` as an index file.  You can create a `.htaccess` file with the following content:

```
 DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for reply, I really appreciate it, this makes sense since I haven’t change anything related with that directory. But as I said I’m a noob in Linux Ubuntu server 16 yet lol.  Would you mind to give me a step by step and where I have to go to edit or create that file??  This can save my life!!! Thank you